# How can I define my javascript to display the images I found in my php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, directory, slideshow

first of all I am new in this and I thank all the people here I learned of.

My problem:
I created a setting where you can upload pictures in the folder "test"in two different ways. 
I want to display the picutes in an automatic slideshow which takes the pictures out of the folder. (Imag 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg are in the folder TEST.)

my PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$dir_path = "test/";
$extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
$phpArray = array();

$dateien=scandir($dir_path);
$anzahl=count($dateien);

    //echo "Anzahl $anzahl";


if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
$files = scandir($dir_path);

for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
{
if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
    {
        $file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
        $extension = $file['extension'];

        while(in_array($extension, $extensions_array))
        {
        // show image

        echo "<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]' style='width:500px;height:500px;'><br>";
           $phpArray []= array($dir_path, $files[$i]); 
           $filename[]= array($files[$i]);
            //echo $i;
            $i++;
        //echo "Anzahl $anzahl";

                if ($i>$anzahl) 
                    {break;}
            }
    }
}
}
$dir_path2 = "uplaods/";
$dateien2=scandir($dir_path);
$anzahl2=count($dateien2);

if ($anzahl2>$anzahl)

?>
```

with the php code I get the folder path and the file name and I could display the pictures seperatly, but not in an slideshow:

MY HTML/JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>automatic slideshow</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
<img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg" style="width:100%" >
<img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg"style="width:100%">
</div>


<script>

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");  / HERE I NEED HELP
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the slideshow code works for the images I defined in the div, but I want to have it out of the folder. I was able to get the filename and the folder path from php to javascript but I was not able to tell javascript to display the picutes out of the folder.

is it even possible?

Comment: Did you put the php inbetween the w3-center?

Comment: Definitely possible there are multiple ways either by java script or in php

Comment: its one file. first the php part, than html with included javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php
$dir_path = "test/";
//$dir_path2 = "uplaods/";
$extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');

if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
    $files = array_slice(scandir($dir_path), 2);
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($file);
        $ext = $ext['extension'];

        if(in_array($ext, $extensions_array))
            $images[] = '<img class="mySlides" src="'. $dir_path . $file .'" style="width:500px;height:500px;">';
    }
}
?>
```

HTML (within PHP file):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>automatic slideshow</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <style>
 .mySlides {display:none;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>
 <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
 <?php echo implode ("<br />", $images); ?>
 </div>


 <script>
  var myIndex = 0;
  carousel();

  function carousel() {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");  //HERE I NEED HELP
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
   }
   myIndex++;
   if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}   
   x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
   setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Flostens each time you reload page, it will add all image files w/ extentions 'jpg','png','jpeg'.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about this, but JavaScript is unable to iterate through files in a directory on a file system (unless you are using server-side JavaScript). One option is to have your PHP script output the URIs (relative or absolute) of the images to a JavaScript array. Another option is to have the PHP script output JavaScript in the HTML head that creates image objects utilizing the URIs (this is good for preloading the images) and place the objects in a JavaScript array. A more complex solution would be for your PHP script to return a JSON array of the image URIs which you could retrieve from your JavaScript with an AJAX GET request.